# List all .mp3 files recursive from directory

Tags: java, android, arrays, mp3

I know this has been asked several times, but i can't adapt the solutions to make it work for me.
I need an string array that returns the absolute path of every mp3 in the directory /music/ and all its subdirectories.

I found this:

```
public void getMp3s(ArrayList<File> list, File dir){
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();

     for(File file : files){
        if(file.isDirectory()){
            getMp3s(list, file);
        }else{

        }
    }
}
```

Everything i need is the method to return musiclist[] which contains the absolute path of the mp3 file. (test/testsub/song.mp3)
(It's fine if it returns files which are not .mp3)

edit:

like this:?

```
getMp3s(ArrayList<File> list, File dir,int i, String[] musiclist){
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();

     for(File file : files){
        if(file.isDirectory()){
            getMp3s(list, file,i, musiclist);
        }else{
           musiclist[i] = file.getAbsolutePath();
           i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *Why* can't you adapt the solutions? What have you tried? It's not clear where the problem is here.

Comment: Why don't you add each absolute file path to a list when they are found within the loop then just return that list at the end?

Comment: i dont understand how to generate an array out of what ever this code does.

Comment: Well "what ever this code does" sounds like you don't understand the existing code. *That* should be your first step. Which bit of this code do you not understand?

Comment: well puts every file + directory in an arraylist. the mayor problem is: if i add for example musiclist[i]= file.getAbsolutePath(); i dont know how to increase/ declare i  without overwriting the same entry over and over again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of your function, declare an arraylist to store the Mp3 paths

```
ArrayList<String> mp3Paths = new ArrayList();
```

Create a method which will return the mp3s in a given directory (including subdirectories)

```
void getMp3s(File f) {
    File[] files;
    if (f.isDirectory() && (files = f.listFiles()) != null) {
        for (File file : files) {
            getMp3s(file);
        }
    }
    else {
        String path = f.getPath();
        if (path.endsWith(".mp3")) {
            mp3Paths.add(f.getPath());
        }
    }
}
```

The above method recursively searches the directory. You start by giving it an initial directory. Everything in that file is listed. If the file is not a directory, the extension is checked against ".mp3" and is added to the mp3 array if found. If the file is a directory, the method is called again on the sub directory. This will recursively loop through the main directory and all of the sub directories.

Comment: first of all thanks for helping. i got the code running for my purposes. it worked once. then i exported the apk to test it on my smart phone and from that point on (god knows why) it stopped working on my virtual phone and real phone. also i did some additions to your code to make it runnable. 
http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/xuaGnxgUU1

the error appears at line 5. for (File file : files) { (Nullpointer Exception)
i dont understand why it worked for once.
i declared mp3Paths global, because i need it kinda often.

Comment: Take a look at my answer. I put a null check in the if statement. I am not really sure how files are structured on a smart-phone, as I wrote this code with PCs in mind.

Comment: use `endsWith` instead of substringing. rename the function to something that reflect what it does. I would also recommend passing the list as a parameter to the function, to be populated, to avoid issues with multiple calls to this function (and possible with multithreading)

Comment: wow, thanks for the improvement. this wasnt the error tho. somehow android changed the permissions on its own (in manifest.xml) so i didnt have acces to storage...gotta love eclipse and android.

Comment: @njzk2, can you edit my post to add in your suggestions?